# How to map relations in large data set "real-life" scenario

Tags: database, performance, dataset

For performance related tests, I'm trying to create a large amount of data (250k,500k,1mill records) and insert it into a DB, while emulating a "real-life" scenario.

I was wondering if there were studies/anyone knows how to best emulate a real-life scenario of data-relations. For example, if I had X amount of different classes, how many of them would be referencing other classes.

The only thing I'm not sure about is how to emulate the relations (inheritence,reference, etc).

Thanks in advanced, Ben.

Comment: your question is so vague and open ended that you probably wont get an answer close to what you're looking for. You will need to review all your tables and the relations and work out rough row counts and relations between them eg: families usually have 2-3 children, cars have 5 wheels (4 + 1 spare) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

one-to-many relationship is usually implemented by a column on the "many" side, which identifies the "one" side.

many-to-many relationship is usually implemented by a separate table which identifies pairs of parent-child.

Based on your question, you're probably dealing with the latter case.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the answer to what I was asking, I need to generate the data and I'm not sure what "rules" I have to generate it with in-order to simulate "real-life" scenario.

Comment: @user966352: could you provide some examples and your current approach which doesn't work?